# SDWebImage caching is taking time to load the image from cache in uicollectionview cell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, sdwebimage, image-caching

I am using SDWebImage library to load images in a collection view .

Library downloads the image from server and caches but when I quit my app and re-run , it takes time to load image from cache.
( placeholder image is displayed for 2-3 secs sometimes even more )

**Code to load image using SDWebImage:**

```
cell.imgPost.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: (post.lowQualityImgUrl) ?? ""), placeholderImage: UIImage(named:"greybg") , options: .refreshCached, progress: { (recievedSize, expectedSize) in

        progressIndicatorView.progress = CGFloat(recievedSize)/CGFloat(expectedSize)

        }, completed: { (image, error, cachetype, url) in

            if image != nil{
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    progresView.removeFromSuperview()
                    progressIndicatorView.removeFromSuperview()
                    cell.progressIndicatorView?.isHidden = true
                    cell.imgPost.image = image

                }
            }
    })
```

Here the caching option used is refresh cache.

Question:
I don't know why collection view cells can't load the images instantly using sdwebimage . As it says sdwebimage is best library for image caching .
Can anyone point out solution /problem ?

**EDIT**
I did left comment in their library , I think it's never a good library.
https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/issues/138

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you setting the image again by using `cell.imgPost.image = image` inside the block.? Its already being set by this `cell.imgPost.sd_setImage(with: ` block.

Comment: @Poles if i don't place the cell.imgpost.image = image then on scrolling image view shows placeholder again 
I don't know what i'm missing

Answer (score 1):

From `SDWebImage` documentation, for `refreshCached`

> ```
>  * Even if the image is cached, respect the HTTP response cache control, and refresh the image from remote location if needed.
>  * The disk caching will be handled by NSURLCache instead of SDWebImage leading to slight performance degradation.
>  * This option helps deal with images changing behind the same request URL, e.g. Facebook graph api profile pics.
>  * If a cached image is refreshed, the completion block is called once with the cached image and again with the final image.
>  *
>  * Use this flag only if you can't make your URLs static with embedded cache busting parameter.
> ```

You should not use `refreshCached` if you don't want images to be cached unless you get different images in same URL. Leave it to default set up and it will handle everything for you.

**EDIT:** Just leave `options` as empty array, []. It should continue with default setup. Your delay is probably because you still have `refreshedCache` in your code.

```
cell.imgPost.sd_setImage(with: NSURL() as URL!, placeholderImage: UIImage(), options: [], progress: { (_, _) in

}, completed: { (_, _, _, _) in

})
```

Comment: problem is image is cached properly .

but on relaunch it is taking time to load from cache (2-3 secs ) delay 
why taking this much delay